# Can an AutoNumber in MS Access randomly change?

Tags: ms-access

We have a fairly simple multi-user database that we use to make Purchase Orders. The PO Number is generated from an AutoNumber field.

Sometime in the last 4 days something happened that made the numbers go from 8518 to 17474. I know that a user can't change this number. I am just wondering what could have caused this?

There are no records in between 8518 and 17474 to show that 9000(ish) records have been made. I am very confused!!

Answer (score 2):

Autonumber fields in Access are updateable for new records. A user can just write a value to the autonumber column, and Access will continue numbering from there.

For example, a query like this could do it:

```
INSERT INTO [Purchase Orders]([PO Number]) VALUES (17473)
```

That will write that value to a new record, and Access will continue on from there.

Also, when copy-pasting, Access will create new autonumbers. The following actions will increment your autonumber seed by the number of records in the table:

When in table view:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> (Select all)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> (Copy)
- Move to new record, select entire row
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> (Paste all records)
- <kbd>Escape</kbd> (oops, didn't mean to copy table)

No new records would've been added since the action was canceled, but only after already generating autonumbers for all those new records.